# Emulate Desfire EV1 on DUALi DE-ABM4

Tags: c++, nfc, mifare, contactless-smartcard, emulation

I have an Desfire EV1 Smart Card and try to read it by DUALi reader.
I'm aware that for the Desfire I need to wrap the command.

Tried sent the simple APDU command like this:

**90 60 00 00 00 00**

```
INT uiLen = 0;
BYTE pbData[256];
BYTE cmd[6] = {0x90,0x60,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};

iDERc = DE_APDU(
            m_sPortNoM,  
            6, cmd, 
            (LPINT)&uiLen, (LPBYTE)pbData);
```

but why the return always : DE_NACK_COUNT_ERROR?

Also tried to send some APDU command to the SAM, always encounter errors. the return code was 1 which is not defined in any Response code definitions.

already send the DE_InitPort and DE_IC_PowerOn command and the return was successful.

Thanks

**EDIT :**

> For DE_APDU command and parameters explanation:
>
> int DE_APDU(int nPort, BYTE datalen, LPBYTE data, LPINT outlen, LPBYTE
>   lpRes)
>
> - It sends and receive data as APDU format defined by ISO7816. Device change it to ISO14443 protocol and send to card, so User can easily
>     use this function without knowing of ISO14443 protocol.
>
> **- Parameters**
>
> - int nPort[in] : Port number.
> - int datalen[in] : Length of LPBYTE data.
> - LPBYTE data[in] : APDU to send to card.
> - LPINT outlen[out] : Length of LPBYTE lpRes
> - LPBYTE lpRes[out] : Response data.

Comment: `90 60 00 00 00 00` is not a valid APDU command. Try sending `90 60 00 00 00` instead.

Comment: And `uiLen` should probably be set to the length of `pbData`.

Comment: Hi @MichaelRoland thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately still got same error.
Based on post here : https://ridrix.wordpress.com/2009/09/19/mifare-desfire-communication-example/
I need to wrap the command to emulate ISO 7816.
I also add some explanation about the DE_APDU command

Comment: I assume you did set `datalen` to 5 when you sent `90 60 00 00 00` (note that ridrix is partially wrong with his wrapping since Lc and DATA are simply not present when Lc = LEN(DATA) = 0), right? Also you clearly have to pass the initial size of the buffer `lpRes` in `outlen` (eventhough it's marked as "out") otherwise the method wouldn't know if the response fits into the buffer.

Comment: Hi @MichaelRoland
Yes already, tried `BYTE cmd[5] = {0x90, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};` the `datalen = 5` and `outlen = 10`
error still same.

Comment: (I do not have this particular reader, but...) what @MichaelRoland says definitely makes sense (i.e. using `INT uiLen = 256;`, `BYTE cmd[5] = {0x90,0x60,0x00,0x00,0x00};` and `DE_APDU(m_sPortNoM, 5, ...)`. Did the reader send RATS (i.e. is the card in ISO-14443-4 mode)?

Comment: PS: Assuming you want to get the GetVersion command working I don't understand why are you mentioning SAM and emulation. Good luck!